# The PHP form doesn't allow break lines

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $fname = $_POST['fname']; 
        $lname = $_POST['lname']; 
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
        $email = $_POST['email']; 
        $mesaj = $_POST['message'];  


        $to = "email@me.r";
        $subject = "Email from Website ";
                     $body = 'Nume - '.$fname.' 
                             Prenume - '.$lname.'
                             Email - '.$email.' 
                             Telefon - '.$phone.'
                             Mesaj - '.$mesaj;
        $headers = "From Contact <$email>";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
        if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
            echo "
                <p class='succes'>Thank you for sending me a message!</p>
                <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=contact-me.php' />";
        } else  {
            echo "<p class='succes'>I am sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.</p>";
        }
    }              
?>
```

I got this form for my contact page, it works, send the message. But the prblem is how the message it is displayed. I got no break lines inside of.. looks very weird.

Whats wrong in the cod?

Comment: Add this to lines - `"\r\n"`

Comment: I got tha same result just one change, I got \r\n instead of \n :)

Comment: this is wrong `"From Contact <$email>"` probably why it's failing. It has to be `"From: Contact <$email>"` and is breaking your header.

Comment: then delete this `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP Documentation you can read useful notes about the way message should be written.
Here it is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

More specifically - the explanation of message parameter. Which says:

`Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters.`

Caution

(Windows only) When PHP is talking to a SMTP server directly, if a full stop is found on the start of a line, it is removed. To counter-act this, replace these occurrences with a double dot.

```
<?php
$text = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $text);
?>
```